# Flutter app on real iPhone device won't open

Tags: ios, flutter

When I install a Flutter app on a **REAL iPhone**, all works fine, but after some time, it just won't open and my developer profile under Settings -> General -> Device Management is just gone.

What is going on here?.

The first approach was that it could be related to a recent OS update that I performed on the device, but this has been already discarded as the reason for this issue.

It keeps happening without me doing anything at all on the iPhone, after some days of using the app.

Comment: usually code signing is an issue, did you follow https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#deploy-to-ios-devices?

Comment: yep, step by step

Comment: is there an error, when running it via android studio? some gradle build failure or something?

Comment: wait, how much time are we talking here? i was thinking while building, but you said days ... maybe a memory leak? or the debug build just expires (even testflight builds expire after 90 days ...)

Comment: not sure after how many days, but looks like after not so many days, the profile is gone, no error so far when running on Android Studio, but it is not possible to run in real iphone from android studio, you need to use xcode.